# Suggestion Popup Window Isn't Draggable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

The popup window in the suggestion review queue isn't draggable unlike the flag popup window for example:
[image]

Update 27/07/2013, Low Quality Posts:
[image]

I would like it to be draggable. Perhaps along the side, all windows can be reviewed to have this option enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be available in the next build, > rev 2013.8.14.943.